# Rust Generics - cannot infer type for type parameter `T`

Tags: generics, rust

I have some Rust FFI code that I would like to apply to `i32, i64, f32, f64` and so on. So using a generic type T would help me to avoid repeating large blocks of code.

In this example, I have cut out `i64` and pasted in `T` (and decorated the fn names with `<T>`). The i64 version works fine.

```rust
use libc::c_char;
use libc::size_t;
use std::slice;
use std::ffi::*; //{CStr, CString,}
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::{Path};

use polars::prelude::*;//{CsvReader, DataType, DataFrame, Series};
use polars::prelude::{Result as PolarResult};

pub struct SeriesC {
    se: Series,
}

impl SeriesC {
    fn new<T>(name: String, data: Vec::<T>) -> SeriesC {
        SeriesC {
            se: Series::new(&name, data),
        }   
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn se_new(
    string: *const c_char,
    data: *const *const i64,
    len: size_t, 
) -> *mut SeriesC {

    let se_name = unsafe {
        CStr::from_ptr(string).to_string_lossy().into_owned()
    };  

    let mut se_data: Vec<i64> = Vec::<i64>::new();
    unsafe {
        assert!(!data.is_null());

        for item in slice::from_raw_parts(data, len as usize) {
            se_data.push(*item as i64);
        };  
    };  

    Box::into_raw(Box::new(SeriesC::new(se_name, se_data)))
}
```

It seems that whatever I try gives me errors. I have also considered Arrays instead of Vecs, but I am pretty sure I want Vecs as the length is not known at compile time. This attempt says:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `polars::prelude::Series: polars::prelude::NamedFrom<Vec<T>, _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:20:17
   |
20 |             se: Series::new(&name, data),
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `polars::prelude::NamedFrom<Vec<T>, _>` is not implemented for `polars::prelude::Series`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <polars::prelude::Series as polars::prelude::NamedFrom<&polars::prelude::Series, str>>
             <polars::prelude::Series as polars::prelude::NamedFrom<T, ListType>>
             <polars::prelude::Series as polars::prelude::NamedFrom<T, T>>
             <polars::prelude::Series as polars::prelude::NamedFrom<T, [&'a str]>>
           and 33 others
```

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Please add all your `use` statements. I get a ton of undeclared types from your code.

Comment: Apologies - I have now edited these in - the code snippet is a subset and does not necessary apply all the ```use``` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler knows that the type is `i64`, it can see that `Series` implements the required `NamedFrom` conversion trait due to the implementation `impl<T> NamedFrom<T, [i64]> for Series where T: AsRef<[i64]>` provided by the polars library.  There isn't an implementation for `NamedFrom` when `T` is totally unbounded -- there are types you could substitute for `T` for which there would be no implementation of `NamedFrom`.

To make this work generically, you need to add a suitable bound so that the compiler knows that there is a `NamedFrom<Vec<T>, [T]>` implementation on `Series`, which will appropriately restrict usage of your `SeriesC::new()` function to types `T` for which such as implementation exists.

```
fn new<T>(name: String, data: Vec::<T>) -> SeriesC
    where Series: NamedFrom<Vec<T>, [T]>
{ ... }
```

Comment: yes - that's the ticket! thanks!!!

Comment: it's still a bit of a mystery to me why you need ```<Vec<T>, [T]>``` bound is that because this is a list of alternate constraints (Vec, Array)? OK - but why does this not also contain the first argument (name: String)?

Comment: @p6steve Look at [the definition of `NamedFrom`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/trait.NamedFrom.html). Note that in `NamedFrom<T, Phantom>`, the `new` function is `fn new(&str, T)`. The first argument is _always_ `&str` regardless of what `T` is, and `T` is the type of the _second_ parameter.

Comment: ha! so that's why it's called 'NamedFrom' !! thanks...